# Android Recycler view: How to Keep adding elements one below the other?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a List of URLs in a String array. Each has list of latest top 10 Apps.

```
String[] List= {"http://example.com/xml","http://eaxmple.org/xml"....};
```

The structure of XML is same and say each of those URLs has 10  tags in them.

After parsing XML, I am using a recycler view to display the tags from each xml file.(About 10 objects).

It works perfectly when I pass only one of the URLs. i.e., I can see 10  on the screen. 
What should I do to have a continuous scrolling recycler view where each URL's tags has to come one below the other? 20  in this case? 
I tried a for loop in addOnScrollListener but when the second URL is passed, the first one is replaced by the second. I want it to be continuous. Keep adding to the existing elements. How to achieve? Any hints?
Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Just add the new 10 items to your adapter data set, and they will be shown below the old ones.

Comment: Thanks Rami43. I'll try this out and see.